# Date Format in pg-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, momentjs, node-postgres

I have tried to insert date into the postgresql in 'dd.mm.yyyy' format.

First inserted the string type, then the date type
`moment(new Date()).format('DD.MM.YYYY')` but in database format always like 'yyyy-mm-dd'

What can I do?

Comment: So you should change column type to varchar, dont use date type

Comment: @RyanNghiem: that is a **really**, really bad advice. Date values should **never** be stored in a `varchar` column.

Comment: A `date` column stores a binary representation of the date. It is not stored in any particular format. Any formatting you _see_ is applied by the program that displays those dates. You need to check that application if you can find a way to configure how it formats date values when displaying them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Ok, thanks, I will explore this direction